# Evitar que Chrome autocomplete form, no funciona autocomplete="off" en input

Tags: formularios, google-chrome, autocompletar

Buenas a todos, estoy teniendo problemas con Google Chrome y el autocompletado.
Quiero que no se autocompleten algunos campos de mi formulario y he añadido el atributo: `autocomplete="off"`

Esto en Chrome no está funcionando, pero en otros navegadores como Firefox si ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se completen solo algunos campos?

He visto por internet como solución alternativa añadir `autocomplete="off"` a la etiqueta `<form>`, pero esto no me sirve, ya que muchos campos si que me gustaría que se autocompletasen...

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="">
<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..." />
<input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos..." />
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico..." />
<input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Código promocional..." autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

**¿Cómo evito que se autocomplete un único campo input en Chrome?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debido a que el problema de **autocompletado** de **Google Chrome** es bastante conocido y ha sido discutido en numerosos foros por usuarios que han tenido este problema, se ha creado una especie de **"parche"** (si se puede llamar así) para solucionar lo que **chrome** ha prohibido. En el diseño por defecto está configurado para ignorar la instruccion de desactivar **autocomplete** ("autocomplete=off"). Este **"parche"** que soluciona tu problema lo muestra **@sergibarca** en su respuesta.

A manera de **complemento** debo agregar que bien podrías hacer que **chrome** intente buscar un **código** inexistente seteando el **autocomplete** del input en cuestión a un valor que sabes que nunca **existirá** en el campo. De esta manera, **chrome** no podrá mostrarte ninguna opción de **autocompletado** porqué no encuentra ninguna que concuerde con el autocomplete.

Esto lo logras en tu caso así:

```
<input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Código promocional..." autocomplete="ÑÖcompletes" />
```

Difícilmente **chrome** encontrará **autocompletar** algo que concuerde con **"ÑÖcompletes"**. Claro está, puedes cambiar este valor por algo que quede más elegante o que te convenga mejor.

Referencias:

Para el parche. [Aquí!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Para el autocomplete con valor inexistente: [Aquí!](https://www.20spokes.com/whiteboard//what-to-do-when-chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off-on-your-form/)

Para observar ambas respuestas ante un problema similar al tuyo: [Aquí](https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/bcd1aa)

Bonus, a Mozilla también le sucedió! [Aquí!](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/desactivar_autocompletado_formulario)

Eso es todo. Un Saludo

Comment: puedes dejar el código link de referencia jejeje tambien me interesa

Answer (score 2):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un input que captura el auto complete ocultado con CSS.

Ejemplo

```html
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="falsocodigo" autocomplete="off" />

<input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Código promocional..." autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Luego de revisar varias páginas con respuestas con códigos en JS, JQuery y demás, encontré entre tantas opciones que esto me resultó al día de hoy (20-08-2019).

Omití agregar autocomplete="off" en la etiqueta FORM y en cada INPUT de tipo TEXT usé autocomplete="new-text":

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" autocomplete="new-text">
```

Mientras que en cada INPUT de tipo PASSWORD:

```
<input type="password" name="clave" autocomplete="new-password">
```

No necesité utilizar otro tipo de campos en mi formulario, pero siguiendo la misma lógica, imagino que se deberá modificar los tipo NUMBER por "new-number" y así según cada tipo.

Espero que les salve la tarde como a mi, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Después de probar muchas opciones, esta es la única que me ha funcionado en Chrome:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" autocomplete="new-text">
```

También funciona con un componente angular o ionic.

```
<ion-searchbar autocomplete="new-text"></ion-searchbar>
```