# evitar texto predictivo en formulario html

Tags: html, html5

estimados tengo un formulario que cuando alguien ingresa desde un telefono android con text predictivo este al momento de ingresar el rut o dni se empieza a llenar y duplicar de forma automatica. quiero saber como evitarlo

```html
<form  method="POST" target="_top" id="login"   action="">
 <input id="style" autocomplete="off" name="style" value="" type="hidden">
     <input id="origin" name="origin" value="" type="hidden">
      <input id="redirect_uri" name="redirect_uri" value="" type="hidden">
     <input id="idrequest" name="idrequest" value="" type="hidden">
     <input id="flow" name="flow" value="" type="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">               
        
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="required rut" placeholder="Rut" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)"  required/>  

   <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>  
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
<a class="no-reg" target="_top" href="recuperarClaveAction.do">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
      
             </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes revisar una respuesta que dí previamente que resuelve parte de tu inconveniente (por lo menos el autocompletado) dirigiendote al siguiente link: [Evitar que Chrome autocomplete form, no funciona autocomplete=“off” en input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129057/evitar-que-chrome-autocomplete-form-no-funciona-autocomplete-off-en-input/129090#129090)

Te explico brevemente lo tratado en el link. Aún cuando existe una propiedad HTML denominada ***autocomplete*** la cual se encarga de controlar si se puede (traduciendo directamente del inglés) autocompletar determinado elemento HTML o no no todos los navegadores soportan esta característica por lo menos no con la configuración por defecto de "autocomplete=off" es necesario realizar un proceso adicional que explicaré más adelante en esta misma respuesta.

En tu segmento de código observo que intentas generar un "parche" para poder evitar el autocompletado de tu **input** rut o dni, sin embargo, tal parche sólo funciona colocando el `autocomplete=off` antes del **input** al cual deseas anularle el autocompletado. En tu caso, sería así:

```
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="parche" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="required rut" placeholder="Rut" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

> El detalle de esta aproximación (según mi experiencia) es que por cada
>   input que no desees que se autocomplete deberás generar otro extra
>   antes de él, es decir, por cada `autocomplete=off` dos inputs
>   estarán asociados.

Una solución que evita la duplicidad de los inputs es la que propongo en la respuesta que anexé al principio y adaptándola a tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="required rut" placeholder="Rut" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" autocomplete="ÑÖcompletes"  required/>
```

La idea es colocar en la propiedad **autocomplete** una palabra que ningún usuario ingresaría o buscaría de esta forma cuando el usuario intente buscar cualquier otra palabra diferente esta no haga "match" con la del autocomplete y por tanto no será mostrado el autocompletado en el input (que es justamente lo que necesitas según planteas). Es necesario que sea así porque navegadores como Chrome no han optimizado el uso de esta etiqueta. Se podría decir que es una especie de bug que tiene Chrome. Si quieres leer sobre este problema de Chrome y más información sobre el autocomplete visita la respuesta que dejé al principio Así evito duplicar los links innecesariamente en esta respuesta.

A continuación tu código completo con la modificación para que no autocomplete:

```html
<form  method="POST" target="_top" id="login"   action="">
 <input id="style" autocomplete="off" name="style" value="" type="hidden">
     <input id="origin" name="origin" value="" type="hidden">
      <input id="redirect_uri" name="redirect_uri" value="" type="hidden">
     <input id="idrequest" name="idrequest" value="" type="hidden">
     <input id="flow" name="flow" value="" type="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">               
        
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="required rut" placeholder="Rut" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" autocomplete="ÑÖcompletes"  required/> 

   <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>  
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
<a class="no-reg" target="_top" href="recuperarClaveAction.do">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
      
             </div>
</form>
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

El atributo que buscas es de `HTML5`:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Recuerda que no funciona en versiones muy viejas de navegadores, por lo regular te funcionará muy bien , saludos.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Lo solución que propones está correcta, sin embargo, trata por favor de anexar código de ejemplo (o la modificación del código que suministre la pregunta) para poder orientar de la mejor manera al OP y pueda sacar el máximo provecho a la colaboración que le estás prestando. Es sólo un consejo para que tu respuesta sea considerada por más usuarios como un gran aporte. Un saludo

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77961/discussion-on-answer-by-elaineee-evitar-texto-predictivo-en-formulario-html).

Comment: El autocomplete está en un input de tipo hidden, eso no me hace nada de sentido. No es leer, es entender, está escribiendo sobre un campo que no tiene el atributo. :)

Comment: He eliminado el "-1" @elaineee mis disculpas por el inconveniente.