# ¿Como puedo borrar los datos enviados via POST o cerrar conexión para que el usuario no tenga acceso al dar click en el boton regresar del navegador?

Tags: php, html5, formularios

Tengo un Form con el siguiente código:

```html
<form action="x.php" method="post">      
<p class="negrita">OPINION</p>
<p class="titulo1">Nombre</p>    
<input id="campo1" class="campostexto1" type="text" name="nombre" required>
<p class="titulo2">Mensaje</p>  
<textarea id="campo2" class="campostexto2" style="font-size: 16px;" cols="40" rows="10" name="campo2" onKeyDown="contador()" onKeyUp="contador()" maxlength="500" required></textarea>
<div>
<div id="enviar"><input  type="submit" value="ENVIAR"></div>
                                             
</div>          
</form>
```

En la otra pagina lo recibo con $nombre = $_POST["campo1"]; $mensaje = $_POST["campo2"]; lo inserto en una base de datos. ¿Como puedo ahi borrar los datos POST? para que cuando el usuario de click en el botón regresar del navegador, ya no le de acceso a la pagina del formulario. O ¿como puedo cerrar la sesión en esas dos paginas para que el usuario deba ir desde el principio?

Comment: Es confuso lo que pides, ¿no quieres que el form recuerde lo que el usuario escribio o no quieres que el usuario pueda acceder de nuevo al formulario?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. En ese punto ya no necesito que el usuario recuerde lo que escribió, pues ya se guardo en una base de datos. Lo que me gustaría es que cuando el usuario le de click atras al boton del navegador, no estén los datos que escribió, ni  que se reenvien.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Evitar que Chrome autocomplete form, no funciona autocomplete="off" en input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129057/evitar-que-chrome-autocomplete-form-no-funciona-autocomplete-off-en-input)

Comment: No, muchas gracias de cualquier forma. Esto es antes de que el usuario envíe el formulario y es para que chrome no auto complete las palabras. Yo lo que busque es después, el usuario ya envió el formulario, ya lo recibí en otra pagina, ya le di respuesta, pero cuando da clic en el boton atras, regresa al formulario, se envian otra vez los datos o los puede volver a enviar. quiero evitar eso

Comment: Quiero evitar que se reenvien los datos, quiero borrarlos.

Comment: Y no sería más fácil mirar si lo que ha enviado el usuario ya lo tienes en la base de datos y si es así ignorarlo? Así dará igual que intente reenviar la misma cosa dos veces. O si no, guarda en una cookie o en localStorage una variable que si está a true no deje enviar el formulario, pero tendrías que cambiar el envío para hacerlo con javascript, no te sirve usar un submit normal. Y de todas maneras podría seguir enviando mensajes si usa modo incógnito o borra las cookies

Comment: Creo que podrías hacerlo mediante `jQuery`, debes de añadir un `id` a tu formulario, es decir, `<form id="mi_formulario" action="x.php" method="post"> ` y después una vez cumple tu `insert` añades este código `echo "<script>$('#mi_formulario')[0].reset();</script>";` para vaciar los **inputs**.

Answer (score 0):

en realidad es bastante simple pero algo tedioso. Lo primero que debes de hacer es focalizar la dirección de la página que tienes actualmente, para posteriormente mediante la función header poder re-direccionar a la misma url pero sin los datos tediosos que representa. Unicamente añade como parámetro en tu php de página una url:

> ```
> <?php
> include 'derivado.php';
> $url="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
> ?>
> ```

ahora añade un textarea o un input a tu formulario con el identificador o nombre "urlPag".

> ```
> <textarea name="urlPag" style="visibility: hidden; display:none"><?php echo "$url"; ?></textarea>
> ```

ahora en tu código php derivado cuando hayas completado el proceso correspondiente redirecciona a la página en la que estabas anteriormente, para ello recibe los datos mediante _GET o _POST.

> ```
> <?php
>
>     if ($_GET) {
>         ProcesoDerivado();
>         $url = $_GET["urlPag"];
>         header("Refresh:0,url=$url");
>     }
>
> function ProcesoDerivado()
> {
> //PROCESO
> }
> ?>
> ```

Como verás la página al ser recargada por esté método no guarda los datos que se enviaron por POST o GET. Entonces así aseguras que no se repita la misma instrucción muchas veces.

Espero de todo corazón que te sirva hehe ~~