# Que no autocomplete la información de inicio de sesion (Login) en formularios de agregar, modificar usuario

Tags: php, login, autocomplete

Estoy trabajando un sistema en PHP con codeigniter, jquery; ya depurando los errores, mi problema es que en los formularios de agregar y modificar usuarios siempre carga la información que guarda chrome en el login, he intentado con autocomplete="newpassword" y me funciona para que no me la complete pero siempre me la ofrece el "Gestionar contraseñas", es mas me aparece hasta en el formulario que hice para cambiar la contraseña.

Tambien cuando se crea un usuario chrome y su gestor de contraseñas manda el aviso de contraseña vulnerada en ese sitio

Les agradezco mucho.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Evitar que Chrome autocomplete form, no funciona autocomplete="off" en input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129057/evitar-que-chrome-autocomplete-form-no-funciona-autocomplete-off-en-input)