# ¿Como eliminar lo que escribí anteriormente en un campo?

Tags: formularios

Quiero saber como puedo eliminar lo que escribí en un campo de un formulario. Para que no me aparezca una lsita.
[image: Esta es una pantalla, igual para mi inicio de sesión]

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet">
                                        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                                            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[A-Za-z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="BarCode" name="nserie">
                                            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="BarCode" name="nserie">Numero de serie o Color</label>
                                            <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Invalido</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Evitar que Chrome autocomplete form, no funciona autocomplete="off" en input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129057/evitar-que-chrome-autocomplete-form-no-funciona-autocomplete-off-en-input)

Answer (score 0):

Para eso existe el atributo autocomplete, que le puedes añadir a tus input, indicándole autocomplete="off", para que no complete tus campos ni muestre lo que haz insertado con anterioridd.

Te dejo la documentación [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos/autocomplete)

```html
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet">
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[A-Za-z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="BarCode" name="nserie" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="BarCode" name="nserie">Numero de serie o Color</label>
        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Invalido</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.